# WSO2 ESB get the tenant name property in the sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB to process the message before send it to an external message broker.
I want to name the destination queue base on the tenant name. But, how can I get the tenant name ?

Comment: I know there is a 'getTenant' method in the management admin services of WSO2 IS but not sure there is one for Integrator. A alternative is to create for each tenant a small file in the registry where you put the tenant name and retrieve that name in the proxy.

Comment: Yes, i'm going to try it. By the way. Because the incoming request contains the tenant as /t/tenant.org/request, I'm trying to get it out of there

Comment: The request is coming in on an API? You can probably define the context as '/t' and define a resource of type uri-template and use /{tenant_name}/request. The tenant will then be available in 'uri.var.tenant_name' property

Comment: Great Jan, however I found the prefix /t/tenant is now appended as default when you deploy the artifact into different tenant context. So, if I define URI template begine with /t/tenant, it will duplicate the tenants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you cannot get the tenant name directly, because as per the code, we are not passing the tenant domain as an individual property in the message context. But you can find this tenant name in the "TransportInURL" property which contains the axis2 message context. That "TransportInURL" property value has formed as below.

- TransportInURL: /t/tenant_domain or tenant_name/api context parts
- eg: /t/wso2.com/abc/v1

Then in order to achieve your requirement, you can use the substring function with the property mediator to isolate the tenant name as the below.

`<property name="tenant" expression="fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($axis2:TransportInURL, '/t/'), '/')"/>`

eg:

- Input: /t/wso2.com/abc/v1
- Result: wso2.com

Sample API: You can see how you can use this property to obtain the tenant name.

```
    <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ABC" context="/t/wso2.com/abc" version="v1" version-type="context">
   <resource methods="GET">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="tenant" expression="fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($axis2:TransportInURL, '/t/'), '/')"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="tenantValue" expression="get-property('tenant')"/>
         </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c985f352f000064009f2f91"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Thank Nadee Poornima agian